# Spring 3.0 @Scheduled annotation not working as expected

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, spring-annotations

I use the `@Scheduled` annotation to make the function `myProcess()` in a Spring MVC application (version 3.0.6.RELEASE running on Apache Tomcat/7.0.26) run *once every hour* (3,600,000 ms = 1 hour):

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 3600000)
public void myProcess() { ... }
```

The function is executed as expected, *but not in the morning* (see the sample log times below for the latest 2 days). This happens every day. I see no exceptions in the log files. Have you got any ideas as to what could be the reason for this strange behavior?

---

```
Feb 13 02:11:15
Feb 13 03:11:16 
Feb 13 06:17:34
Feb 13 06:45:55 
Feb 13 07:03:22
Feb 13 07:31:57
Feb 13 08:11:16 
Feb 13 09:11:18
Feb 13 10:11:18 
Feb 13 11:11:28 

Feb 14 01:11:37
Feb 14 02:11:29
Feb 14 03:11:29 
Feb 14 06:19:51
Feb 14 06:49:17
Feb 14 07:35:57
Feb 14 08:11:29
Feb 14 09:11:35
```

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using?

Comment: @sp00m: Thanks, Spring version is 3.0.6.RELEASE. I updated the question with this info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same kind of problem, but using the `cron` attribute:

```java
// every day at midnight
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * ?")
public void myProcess() {
}
```

I can't really remember the behavior it had, but it wasn't the one I expected. I finally found that it was probably depending on a bug in Spring 3.0.x. The solution I tried (and which worked), was to declare the task in the *applicationContext.xml* file, **in addition to the annotation**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

    ...

    <!-- scheduling and async -->
    <task:annotation-driven />
    <task:scheduled-tasks>
      <task:scheduled ref="myProcessHandler" method="myProcess" fixed-delay="0" />
    </task:scheduled-tasks>
    <bean id="myProcessHandler" class="path.to.MyProcessHandler" />

    ...

</beans>
```

Even if the `fixed-delay` attribute is necessary to fix the bug (as far as I know), **it isn't taken into account**, while the `cron` attribute of the `@Scheduled` annotation is.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Oh, a possible bug. I suspected that. I'll look into your proposed solution and see if I can make it work.

Comment: Not sure if I missed a point, but if I used _both_ XML and annotation, I got two simultaneous processes. Only XML didn't work either, because the event only fired once and never again. So I switched to `cron` and added `<task:scheduled ref="myProcessHandler" method="myProcess" cron="0 0 * * * ?" />` to _root-context.xml_ (had to remove `<task:annotation-driven />`). That finally worked.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot give you an answer to the specific question, I would try using the recent version of Spring (3.2) because between 3.0 and 3.1 as far as I know significant changes have been implemented in this area.

However, in my experience I found the cronTrigger much better in all cases (it can do of course everything the fixedRate can and so much more)

Just define your properties like this:

```
<util:properties id="props" location=classpath:/application.properties" />
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="props"  />
<task:annotation-driven />
```

And then use it:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${cron.expression}")
public void scheduledTask() throws .. { .. }
```

Where in the application.properties you have something like:
cron.expression = 0 0/60 * * * ?

Comment: Yeah, `cron` seems like a better choice for me. I like `fixedRate` though because it kicks off right when I start the application, which is very handy when it comes to debugging. Otherwise I need to wait for the `cron` time.

Comment: Yes that's true. You can however have both :)

Comment: I tried `@Scheduled(cron="0 0 * * * ?")`. Still the same irregular execution pattern appears. It gives more weight to the sp00m comment about possible bugs in Spring 3.0.x.

Comment: As I already suggested, do upgrade to 3.2, to my knowledge there isn't anything out there which depends on Spring 3.0.x so why wouldn't you.

Comment: I am working with a legacy system and worried about backward-incompatibility issues between 3.2 and 3.0. The cost of upgrading and verifying that everything works as expected is currently too high. Sooner or later of course I will need to upgrade.